# Can 2FA help handle mixed personal and business accounts after leaving a company?

Tags: passwords, email, google, sms

I do not want a super administrator in Google Apps to log to my account after leaving company, so I enabled 2-step verification. He could login to many sites as me with just a link in "forget password" email.

After changing my password in panel he will not be able to login without sms code. But what if he delete my account and recreate it with the same email address? Will google remeber settings?

Comment: Why does an administrator have your Google Apps login information in the first place?  If it's a business account, you don't have any right to it after you leave.  If it's personal they should never have it in the first place.

Comment: 1. Google Apps administrator doesn't have my login information, but super administrator can reset to new password at any time.

2. I do not want to use that account anymore, but that person can use it to login to many sites and can post anything signed by my name, even if that accounts were only business, ex. with facebook account I have access to company fanpage.

Comment: Ok, so if I understand correctly, you used your Google account associated with your former employer to sign up for a bunch of websites and now you are worried that they could log in to the other services as you?

Answer (score 3):

If I understand your problem correctly, it sounds like the fundamental issue is that you are trying to block your former company from accessing your former company account because you used it for setting up accounts on other sites.  Depending on your jurisdiction, this might even be considered something your former company could go after you for since you are trying to prevent them from accessing their resource which you misused (even if the misuse was unintentional).  It is unlikely that you had ownership of the account, so you are effectively trying to prevent your former employer from using their property.

Your best bet is probably to talk to those sites that you used it on and see if you can switch those accounts that are your personal accounts to be based off a personal account that you control.  If they are also business related accounts, then you likely no longer have a right to the accounts and shouldn't be worried about it.  If you are worried about your company using your name after you left, you could possibly ask the sites about closing the account for you.

Answer (score 1):

> I do not want a super administrator in Google Apps to log to my account after leaving company

No matter what authentication you set for yourself, the super user can access your account. That's the principle of being "root". The administrator can [disable 2FA for any account](http://support.google.com/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=2537800) and can [reset the password](http://support.google.com/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=33319&topic=14588&ctx=topic).

If you've left the company, they can lock you out and have access to your account. Period.

Comment: Thanks, I do not know about disabling 2FA per account. This means I should take care of my past emails and gtalk chats from the history.